# Agm Maps change the level/floor of building

Tags: angular, google-maps, ionic-framework, google-maps-markers

it is a possible to change the level of view ( not the zoom ) from the map? In the following image, it displays the floor 0, and I would like to change to display the floor 1.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pRNU.jpg

Is there any way to could change the floor / level of building?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Currently there are no available feature of this under Google Maps APIs. However, you may file a Feature Request in [Issue Tracker of Google Maps Platform](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188851&template=787413) in order for the engineers to review the feasibility of the feature, please also attach your use case when filing the Feature Request as this will help the engineers to address your Feature Request in shorter time.